# Is $f(t-N t_0)=\sin(2\pi f_0t)\cos(2\pi f_1t)$ always true?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Is it true that multiplying two sinusoidal functions, always result in some periodic waveform.

i-e $$f(t-N t_0)=\sin(2\pi f_0t) \cos(2\pi f_1t)$$

If so, then how can we calculate the period ( $t_0$) of the resulting function, f(t) ?

Moreover, is it correct to say that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(2 \pi f_1 t)\sin(2 \pi f_2 t)\ dt= \delta(f_1-f_2)$$

thanks

Comment: can you say more about your notation $f(t-Nt_0)$?

Comment: $N ∈ \mathbb{N}$,$t_0$ is the period of periodic function $f(t)$

Comment: I don't get it. $f$ is your function? which product?

Comment: $f(t)=f(t-N \cdot t_0)$ if $f$ is periodic with period $t_0$.

Comment: ok for $f$. And what product are you talking about?

Comment: Product of two sinusoids, of arbitrary frequencies, is always Periodic or Not ? If Yes, then how to calculate the period of resulting waveform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In general no, but it is often a yes.
   You have the following formula:
   $$
   \sin(2\pi f_0 t + \phi) \sin(2\pi f_1 t) =\frac 12\left[
   \cos(2\pi (f_0-f_1) t + \phi) + \cos(2\pi (f_0+f_1) t + \phi)
   \right]
   $$
   It is not periodic if the ratio of frequencies of both signals is not a rational number.
2. The integral you talk about is not well defined from the mathematical point of view
   of Lebesgue integral. 
   It may be true in terms of distributions, I need a more precise statement (you can't define a product of distributions, as far as I know).